# devise sign out user before resetting password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like it so that when a user clicks a "reset my password" link in email, it signs them out before rendering the password reset form if they are signed in.  What happens now is it throws a flash "You are already signed in."  I am hoping this is a config or a common pattern.

Thanks for any help,
kevin

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution, in my passwords controller, i added this:

```
def require_no_authentication
    # this is a polymorphic override of devise controller, this is where they check
    # for if a user is already signed in, if they are editing their password then
    # sign them out before taking them to the password reset
    if params[:action] == "edit" and current_user
        sign_out(current_user)
    end
    super    
end
```